# Set maxElements property in select2 tokenizer using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tokeninput

I use [jQuery Tokenize](https://www.zellerda.com/projects/tokenize) for selecting multiple values in drop down.My requirement is that i want to disable drop down after user select one element.

**HTML Code**

```
<select id="myinput" multiple="multiple"class="tokenize-sample" required="required" maxElements=1></select>
```

To set properties to drop down we can use following code snippet.But in my case it will draw a  another drop down with existing one.So i want to add properties to HTML code like above code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myinput').tokenize({
    maxElements: 1
});
</script>
```

This is how i call methods on drop down and this is working fine.but my requirement is add properties on drop down after initialization.

```
$("#myinput").data('tokenize').disable();
```

if anyone knows how to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood but if you want to disable the Tokenize after adding an element you can do this :

```
$('#myinput').tokenize({
  onAddToken: function() {$("#myinput").data('tokenize').disable();},
  maxElements: 1
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e6s96v2s/